# Docker HealthChecks fail on ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, docker, health-check

Im trying to dockerize an ASP.NET application, however I am having some issues with the health checks, I have a simple program like

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapHealthChecks( "/health" );

app.Run();
```

And when I run it locally, it all works fine and I can see that the healthchecks return healthy, however when I run it in a docker container with the following docker-compose

```
version: '3.2'

services:
asp-service:
  image: bitnami/dotnet-sdk
  working_dir: /app
  command: "./run.sh"
  volumes:
    - "./:/app:rw"
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  healthcheck:
    test: curl --fail https://asp-service:8080/health || exit 1
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 30s
    retries: 3
```

Where run.sh is a simple script which just runs `dotnet run` I can see the service runs fine, however when I run `docker ps` I can see the status returns health: unhealthy

Comment: What's the output of `docker exec -it <container> curl -k https://localhost:8080/health` ? I wouldn't be surprised if it is `curl: command not found`.

Comment: Thats weird, executed the command and it returns healthy, however healthchecks still fail?

Comment: The healthcheck test should use localhost as pointed out by @David T.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that and it still returns unhealthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be one of two issues:

1. The healthcheck can't resolve the hostname, `asp-service`. Try pointing the curl command to localhost:8080 instead.
2. Your service is either insecure and needs to use `http` instead of `https` or you need to provide your certificates to the curl command. It's unusual for local services to be secured, so I'm assuming that you didn't mean to use `https`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I already tried both of these things and neither worked, its still saying the container is unhealthy
I also tried adding -k to the curl command to ignore cert errors and that didnt work either.

Comment: Can you follow these instructions and see what the healthcheck log output is?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42738182/1563240

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply here, I got it working in the end, I had to set it to localhost:8080 using https and add the -k flag to ignore the cert errors. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 4):

If your image build base ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0, curl isn't include in os runtime, so to fix issue add command to install curl into base image.
Docker file example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

And docker-compose file you can healthy check

```
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --fail http://localhost:80/health || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```