# why am I unable to health check container with image: pvermeyden/nodejs-hello-world

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am implementing reverse proxy using caddy. I am trying to health check my container with healthcheck directive. but it always shows that the container is unhealthy. here is my test command ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080"]. I want to make a request to my app.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: caddy:2.6.2-alpine
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      #- ./caddy.json:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - ./caddy.json:/etc/caddy/config.json
    command: caddy run --config /etc/caddy/config.json
  app:
    image: pvermeyden/nodejs-hello-world:a1e8cf1edcc04e6d905078aed9861807f6da0da4
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "8080:80" 
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080"]
      interval: 2s
      start_period: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

**Caddyfile**

```
localhost:80 {
    reverse_proxy app:80
}
```

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                                           NAMES
998bfde80bd7   pvermeyden/nodejs-hello-world:a1e8cf1edcc04e6d905078aed9861807f6da0da4   "node index.js"          19 seconds ago   Up 17 seconds (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                           node
98a5670fd3a1   postgres                                                                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes               0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp                       postgres
e3a928431184   caddy:2.6.2-alpine                                                       "caddy run --config …"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes               443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 2019/tcp, 443/udp   caddy
```

**sudo docker logs node**

```
Server is now listening
```

$curl  http://localhost

```
hello world
```

$curl  http://localhost:8080

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737957/how-to-view-docker-compose-healthcheck-logs) question to check specific error of health check. In your case it is

```
> docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" node | jq
{
  "Status": "unhealthy",
  "FailingStreak": 29,
  "Log": [
    {
      "Start": "2023-02-03T11:30:59.709237332Z",
      "End": "2023-02-03T11:30:59.771304098Z",
      "ExitCode": -1,
      "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"
    },
```

You need to install curl and ensure it is available in $PATH.